# Default-568h@2x.png for iPhone5

Tags: iphone, ios, splash-screen, iphone-5, launching-application

I want to update my app so that can be deployed on iPhone5.

Xcode(4.5) has a Default-568h@2x.png which is a black image(640X1136).

In iPhone5's simulator, it still loads the old Default@2x.png. I wanted to know whether it will be same on the actual device ?

Thanx !!!

Comment: Are you sure you were using the iPhone 5 simulator? Because yes, it will show that image on the real device.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Switch to the "iPhone (Retina 4-inch)" device from the Hardware menu in the simulator and you should see the iPhone 5 default image on launch.

Comment: oh it is right, I clean and rebuild the app, it is like what you said, maybe some thing cached before.

Answer (score 5):

Happens to me when I launch iPhone 4" simulator with **iOS 5.1**. When changed to **iOS 6**, launch image is OK.

Comment: because you have to clean and rebuild. try even uninstalling the app from simulator manually or even reset the simulator data. Something got cached in your 5.1 simulator.